# Error running unit tests using pytest - AttributeError: 'TestCaseFunction' object has no attribute 'get_marker'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am using pytest 5.4.1 with python 3.6

Code:

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_upper(self):
        self.assertEqual('foo'.upper(), 'FOO')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Running `pytest` gives the following error:

```
Testing started at 06:08 ...
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2019.2\helpers\pycharm\_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path E:/Folder1/Project1/src/Project1.Api/tests/test1.py
Launching pytest with arguments E:/Folder1/Project1/src/Project1.Api/tests/test1.py in E:\Folder1\Project1\src\Project1.Api\tests

============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.5, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.5.3, pluggy-0.13.1 -- C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\python.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: E:\Folder1\Project1\src\Project1.Api\tests
plugins: arraydiff-0.2, cov-2.8.1, doctestplus-0.1.3, openfiles-0.3.0, remotedata-0.2.1
collecting ... collected 1 item

test1.py::TestStringMethods::test_upper ERROR                            [100%]
test setup failed
item = <TestCaseFunction test_upper>

    def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    
>       remote_data = item.get_marker('remote_data')
E       AttributeError: 'TestCaseFunction' object has no attribute 'get_marker'

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pytest_remotedata\plugin.py:59: AttributeError

Assertion failed


=================================== ERRORS ====================================
_______________ ERROR at setup of TestStringMethods.test_upper ________________

item = <TestCaseFunction test_upper>

    def pytest_runtest_setup(item):
    
>       remote_data = item.get_marker('remote_data')
E       AttributeError: 'TestCaseFunction' object has no attribute 'get_marker'

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pytest_remotedata\plugin.py:59: AttributeError
=========================== short test summary info ===========================
ERROR test1.py::TestStringMethods::test_upper - AttributeError: 'TestCaseFunc...
============================== 1 error in 0.04s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 0

Assertion failed

Assertion failed
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Without having any code to look at, it's hard to figure out what the issue is aside for the fact that you're calling get_marker() on TestCaseFunction which apparently doesn't have the get_marker attribute.

Comment: now updated with unittest code and full output

Comment: For me it's running fine

Comment: what version of pytest-cov and pytest-remotedata do you have?

Comment: pytest-cov==2.8.1; pytest-remotedata==0.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `get_marker` has been renamed `get_closest_marker` . In [this issue](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/4608) on GitHub, you can see that @arvindpdmn suggests upgrading `pytest-remotedata==0.3.0` to `pytest-remotedata==0.3.2`, so assuming you are using `pip` for installing dependencies, run the following command:

```sh
pip install -U pytest-remotedata
```

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the error output, the problem is in the pytest-remotedata package.

```
AttributeError: 'TestCaseFunction' object has no attribute 'get_marker'

c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\shared\anaconda3_64\lib\site-packages\pytest_remotedata\plugin.py:59: AttributeError
```

The error got resolved upon upgrading the `pytest-remotedata` package to latest version (0.3.2):

```
pip install --upgrade pytest-remotedata
```